# Como somar um numero com uma string

Tags: javascript

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mao1 = "goncalo1";
var mao2 = 1;
var mao3 = mao1+mao2;

window.alert(mao3);

</script>
```

O que pretendia era que a var mao3, mostrasse goncalo2 e não goncalo11, como poderei fazer isso?

Comment: Para fazer isso vc vai precisar separar o que for número da sua string, existem mil formas de fazer isso, qual é o seu objetivo principal com isso?

Comment: Eu sabia, que existia uma function que fazia isso, só não estou lembrado qual.

Comment: Quais são as strings possíveis? Qualquer padrão de entrada? Numeros no meio da string também devem ser somadas?

Answer (score 1):

```
var mao1 = "goncalo1";
var mao2 = 1;
var mao1Numero = mao1.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
var mao3 =  mao1.replace(/[0-9]/g,'') +  (parseInt(mao1Numero) + mao2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Montei uma função mais abrangente que aceite strings tipo `gonc4lo1` e que faça uma somatória desses números no meio da palavra alem da `mao2`

```js
function calcular() {
  var mao1 = document.getElementById('mao1').value;
  var mao2 = document.getElementById('mao2').value;
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = operar(mao1, mao2);
}

function operar(a, b) {
  return a.match(/\D+/g).join('') +  (a.match(/\d+/g).reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b), 0) + parseInt(b));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button><br/><br/>
<div id="resultado"></div>
<br/><br/>
mao1: <input id="mao1" type="text"><br/> mao2: 0 <input id="mao2" type="range" max="10" onblur="document.getElementById('valor').innerHTML = '(selecionado '+this.value+')'" value="0"> 10 <span id="valor"><span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça desta forma:

```
var mao1 = "Carlos1";
var mao2 = 1;
var mao3 = mao1.replace(/[0-9]/, parseInt(mao1.match(/[0-9]/)) + mao2);
```

Answer (score -3):

Assim como os colegas responderam

Você pode usar também o [template](https://byexample.xyz/javascript/ECMAScript2015/templateLiterals/?gclid=CjwKCAjwqZSlBhBwEiwAfoZUIBOvLkwIIGjLBI5Ysk7N3BLHHC_tMBDavoJ1uz4rIxFfmKFlPu3rLxoCsLMQAvD_BwE) string para mostrar o resultado

Veja um exemplo

```js
var mao1 = "goncalo1";
var mao2 = 1;
var mao1Numero = parseInt(mao1.replace(/([^\d])+/gim, ''));
var mao3 =  `${mao1.replace(/[0-9]/g,'')}${(mao1Numero + mao2)}`
console.log(mao3)
```

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score -4):

A concatenação das variáveis mao1 e mao2 resultará em "goncalo11" porque o valor de mao2 é convertido implicitamente em uma string durante a concatenação. Isso ocorre porque a operação de adição (+) em JavaScript é sobrecarregada, o que significa que seu comportamento varia dependendo dos tipos dos operandos. Quando pelo menos um dos operandos é uma string, a operação + realiza a concatenação.

Portanto, para obter o resultado "goncalo2", você só precisa garantir que mao1 e mao2 sejam declarados corretamente e realizar a concatenação sem converter explicitamente mao2 em uma string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mao1 = "goncalo1";
  var mao2 = 1;
  var mao3 = mao1 + mao2.toString();

  window.alert(mao3);
</script>
```

Comment: O primeiro parágrafo está correto, mas o código no final não. Esse código também resulta em "goncalo11", [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/IMjMsD)